# Errors in tutorial_06 :FileNotFoundError

Tags: flow-project

It can't generate `.net.xml` file after I run the command in tutorials 06:

```
# create the environment
env = TestEnv(
    env_params=env_params,
    sim_params=sim_params,
    network=network
)

# run the simulation for 1000 steps
exp = Experiment(env=env)
exp.run(1, 1000)
```

It shows errors as follows:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-51d74bed16cd> in <module>
      3     env_params=env_params,
      4     sim_params=sim_params,
----> 5     network=network
      6 )
      7 

~/flow-master/flow/envs/base.py in __init__(self, env_params, sim_params, network, simulator, scenario)
    156         # use the network class's network parameters to generate the necessary
    157         # network components within the network kernel
--> 158         self.k.network.generate_network(self.network)
    159 
    160         # initial the vehicles kernel using the VehicleParams object

~/flow-master/flow/core/kernel/network/traci.py in generate_network(self, network)
    125         elif self.network.net_params.osm_path is not None:
    126             self._edges, self._connections = self.generate_net_from_osm(
--> 127                 self.network.net_params)
    128         else:
    129             # combine all connections into a list

~/flow-master/flow/core/kernel/network/traci.py in generate_net_from_osm(self, net_params)
    577 
    578         # collect data from the generated network configuration file
--> 579         edges_dict, conn_dict = self._import_edges_from_net(net_params)
    580 
    581         return edges_dict, conn_dict

~/flow-master/flow/core/kernel/network/traci.py in _import_edges_from_net(self, net_params)
    841         net_path = os.path.join(self.cfg_path, self.netfn) \
    842             if net_params.template is None else self.netfn
--> 843         tree = ElementTree.parse(net_path, parser=parser)
    844         root = tree.getroot()
    845 

~/anaconda3/envs/flow/lib/python3.6/xml/etree/ElementTree.py in parse(source, parser)
   1194     """
   1195     tree = ElementTree()
-> 1196     tree.parse(source, parser)
   1197     return tree
   1198 

~/anaconda3/envs/flow/lib/python3.6/xml/etree/ElementTree.py in parse(self, source, parser)
    584         close_source = False
    585         if not hasattr(source, "read"):
--> 586             source = open(source, "rb")
    587             close_source = True
    588         try:

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/qmark/flow-master/flow/core/kernel/network/debug/cfg/bay_bridge_20191112-1204001573531440.9655352.net.xml'
```

Answer (score 1):

I found that my path of SUMO in '.bashrc' is wrong, it should be

```
export PATH="$HOME/sumo_binaries/bin:$PATH"
export SUMO_HOME="$HOME/sumo_binaries/bin"
```